# How to retrieve Lead.Status picklist via metadata API?

Tags: metadata-api

I executed a retrieve via the metadata API with the following package xml:

```
<types>
   <members>Lead.Status</members>
   <name>CustomField</name>
</types>
```

From this i got the following metadata snippet from Lead.object:

```
<fields>
    <fullName>Status</fullName>
    <trackFeedHistory>true</trackFeedHistory>
    <type>Picklist</type>
</fields>
```

But where is the actual values for the picklist? Is there something particular about lead.status that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you are on API version 38.0 or later, this is what the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/manifest_samples.htm) states:

> **Standard Picklist Fields**
>
> In API version 38.0 and later, the StandardValueSet type represents
>   standard picklists. Picklists are no longer represented by fields as
>   in earlier versions.

You will need to add the below element in your package.xml to retrieve the Lead' standard Status field (you can find more on the standard value sets [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/standardvalueset_names.htm)):

```
<types>
   <members>LeadStatus</members>
    <name>StandardValueSet</name>
</types>
```

Once retrieved, the values appear as in the below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Note that the Standard Value Set metadata type does not offer wildcard support so you cannot use * to retrieve all the members. You will need to specifically add each individual component name that you want to retrieve. Reference to Salesforce documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_standardvalueset.htm

Answer (score 2):

LeadStatus is a standard picklist field. When using Metadata API version 38.0, standard picklist values are available through the StandardValueSet Metadata object.

package.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata"> 
<types> 
<members>LeadStatus</members> 
<name>StandardValueSet</name> 
</types> 
<version>38.0</version> 
</Package>
```

Source 1: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000247180&type=1

Source 2: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/standardvalueset_names.htm